# Embedded tomcat app with maven works with mvn tomcat7:run, but the jar produced from mvn package does not

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, maven-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.nextcoder.com/?p=1351) to make my webapp into a jar file.  If I do `mvn tomcat7:run` the app works great.  But if I use `mvn package` to generate the jar file and execute the jar every page has a 404 error saying The requested resource is not available.  I have been trying to solve this most of the day with no luck. Here is what my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>HVF</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>HVF</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<profiles>
        <profile>
                <id>test</id>
                <activation>
                        <property>
                                <name>test</name>
                                <value>dev</value>
                        </property>
                </activation>
                <properties>
                </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdf-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                                <id>tomcat-run</id>
                                <goals>
                                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                        <path>/HVF</path>
                                        <attachArtifactClassifier>exec-war</attachArtifactClassifier>
                                        <attachArtifactClassifierType>jar</attachArtifactClassifierType>
                                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                                        <finalName>HVF.jar</finalName>
                                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                                </configuration>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
                      <version>7.0.53</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  At this point I'm at a loss for what to try next.

Comment: mvn package should generate a war, how are you "Executing" it

Comment: I'm following this page: http://www.nextcoder.com/?p=1351 and using this: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/executable-war-jar.html plugin so maven will generate a jar with the embedded server

Comment: what url are you hitting